# unable to load php page in android webview

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, webview

i have a php page which is hosted on my website the link is like **www.example.com/example1/sample.php?id=41**

this page contains dynamically generated html code.

i have written a code in android to load this url in webview as below

```
String id=41;
webViewObj=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webViewObj.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);  
webViewObj.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
webViewObj.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);  
webViewObj.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);  
webViewObj.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webViewObj.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
String url="http://www.example.com/example1/sample.php?id=" + id;
webViewObj.loadUrl(url);
```

but the webview is not displaying dynamic content and only displaying the basic static html contents

Sample.php Code below:

```
<?php
$company_id=$_REQUEST["id"];
include_once './db_functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
//get username of company
$get_username="Select username from CP_Company_Details where id=".(int)$company_id."";
$exec_get_username=mysql_query($get_username);
if (!$exec_get_username) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
else{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($exec_get_username)){
          $username=$row[0];
     }
}
$get_no_of_parking="Select * from CP_ParkingAvailable where username='".$username."' ";
$exec_no_of_parking=mysql_query($get_no_of_parking);while($data=mysql_fetch_array($exec_no_of_parking)){                             $total_parking=$data["no_of_parking"];
}
$total_row=$total_parking/10;
if(is_float($total_row)){
    $remaining=explode(".",$total_row);
    $total_row=round($total_row);
}
$table="";
$table= "<table id='slot' width='100%' border='2' height='100%'>";
$cnt=1;

for($i=1;$i<=$total_row;$i++){
    $table.= "<tr>";
    for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++){
        if($cnt<=$total_parking)
        {
        $table.= "<td><input type='checkbox' id='chk".$cnt."' value='P".$cnt."' name='chk".$cnt."' onchange='book(chk".$cnt.");'>P".$cnt."</td>";
        $cnt=$cnt+1;
        }
    }
    $table.= "</tr>";
}
$table.= "</table>";
echo $table;
?>
```

please help

Comment: What are you getting in logcat

Comment: post your sample.php page